# Can you store arithmetic operators in an array i,e(+, -, *, /) in C++

Tags: c++

I want to make a program that takes 4 numbers eg.(a, b, c and d) and checks if using arithmetic operators i can make the first 3 numbers result to the fourth number, like if the input is (3, 4, 5, 23) this will check out true because 
3 + 4 * 5 = 23,So i want to make an array that has the operators and use a loop to check every possible combination, Hope i made it clear.

Edit:

Its actually codeforces problem, given 4 numbers. Check whether he could get the fourth number by using the arithmetic operators (+,−,×) between the other three numbers. Knowing that an operator can be used only once. in this format ->(a□b□c=d).My question was if there is a way to make it automatic or do i have to code every possibility manually So sorry for any confusion i may have caused.

Comment: Can you post sample code of what you've tried so far? Or roughly what you want to work?

Comment: You can. Not sure how it will help you in this case, but you can regardless. This is more or less a simplified backtracking problem from the looks of it.

Comment: Also, problem needs a bit more clarification: does the precedence of the operators matter? And can you permute the first 3 numbers?

Comment: yes precedence is important and the 4 numbers are just an example

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't store the operators in an array, but you could make wrapper functions for them and store *those* in an array.

```
int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

int sub(int a, int b) {
    return a - b;
}

int mul(int a, int b) {
    return a * b;
}

int div(int a, int b) {
    return a / b;
}

typedef int (*funptr)(int, int);

funptr arr[] = { add, sub, mul, div };
```

You can then call them like:

```
(arr[1])(2, 1)   // call sub(2, 1)
```

The parentheses around `arr[1]` aren't needed in this case, but I like to put them for clarity.

Comment: Oops, that's the copy pasta at work. Thanks @Yksisarvinen!

Answer (score 2):

No. You'd have to write a program to work this out. You could store something like function pointers to the arithmetic operators in an array, but I don't think that would help solve your problem. You'd still have to write the code to solve your problem.

Comment: so i need to make an if statement for every possibility?

Answer (score 2):

Adding onto @CoffeeTableEspresso's answer, you can also put those function pointers into a map.

```cpp
int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

int sub(int a, int b) {
    return a - b;
}

int mul(int a, int b) {
    return a * b;
}

int div(int a, int b) {
    return a / b;
}

typedef int (*funptr)(int, int);

std::map<char,funptr> operators = { 
    {'+', add}, 
    {'-', sub}, 
    {'*', mul}, 
    {'/', div}};
```

Then you can do

```cpp
operators['+'](4,7);
```

Which might be a bit more readable, and you can iterate through these more easily.

Comment: but it IS slower

Comment: That is indeed true, thought I don't think it would be slower by a too significant amount.

IMO the readability is worth it, and it's more flexible easier to change/pass around. Keys can also be strings and other data types.  A map is probably better if you have tons of functions that you're adding/removing often. (which is what I've used it for in the past)

Answer (score 2):

I thought I would submit a compete answer. This works for positive numbers. It may take a bit more work to cover all the possibilities. And it does not answer to CoffeeTableEspresso's question about precedence. But it may help with your last question about `if` statements.

```
#include <iostream>
namespace {
    auto add = [](int a, int b) {return a + b; };
    auto sub = [](int a, int b) {return a - b; };
    auto mult = [](int a, int b) {return a * b; };
    auto divd = [](int a, int b) {return b ? a / b : -1; };
    std::vector<int(*)(int, int)> ops = { add,sub,mult,divd };
}
int check(int* params)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        for (size_t j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
        {
            auto result = ops[i](params[0], ops[j](params[1], params[2]));
            if (params[3] == result)
                return result;
            else
                std::cout << result << std::endl;
        }
    return -1;

}
int main()
{
    int params[] = { 3, 4, 5, 23 };
    std::cout << check(params);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Operators `* /` have a higher precedence than `+ -`, so `operator[i](A, operator[j](B, C))` solution doesn't really work.

You can write a little string calculator, and cycle through char-operators:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

double calculate(std::string str)
{
    // calculator there
    return -1;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<char> op = {'+', '-', '*', '/'};
    std::vector<int>  a  = { 96, 3, 10, 42 };

    for (auto op1: op)
        for (auto op2: op)
        {
            std::stringstream ss;
            ss << a[0] << op1 << a[1] << op2 << a[2];
            double result = calculate( ss.str());

            if (std::abs(a[3] - result) < 1E-6)
                std::cout << ss.str() << " = " << a[3];
            else
                std::cout << ss.str() << " = " << result << " != " << a[3];
        }
}
```